# Scheduled signal to Durable Entity fires immediately in Azure Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to have a very lightweight approach where I expose an HTTP endpoint (trigger) that somewhat exposes a Durable Entity (actor) and has the actor perform work on a frequent basis.

The logic in my HTTP trigger is like this:

1. Check if entity with uid already exists
2. If not, signal entity and fire `InitializeMonitoringAsync` method on the actor
3. If yes, call entity state on the actor and return some values
4. Once initialized, the actor (durable entity) should frequently call the `RefreshActionAsync` on its own.

The issue I have is that the Refresh method seems to keep executing constantly, without the configured delays to be taken into account.  What am I missing?

**Update (workaround)**:

Apparently, when I change the interface methods (that now return a `Task`) to methods that return `void` (and I change the signal call to : `e => e.RefreshActionAsync()`), then it seems to work.  But I don't understand why, and this doesn't seem to be a documented limitation either.

The code below:

**Entity interface**

```cs
public interface IReproEntity
{
    Task RefreshActionAsync();
    Task InitializeMonitoringAsync();
}
```

**Entity function**

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ReproEntity : IReproEntity
{
    [JsonProperty] public bool Activated { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty] public int LoopCount { get; set; }

    public Task InitializeMonitoringAsync()
    {
        ScheduleNext(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10));
        Activated = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task RefreshActionAsync()
    {
        LoopCount += 1;
        ScheduleNext();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void ScheduleNext(DateTime nextSchedule = default)
    {
        if (nextSchedule == default) nextSchedule = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30);
        Entity.Current.SignalEntity<IReproEntity>(Entity.Current.EntityId, nextSchedule,
            async (e) => await e.RefreshActionAsync());
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(ReproEntity))]
    public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext ctx)
    {
        return ctx.DispatchAsync<ReproEntity>();
    }
}
```

**HTTP Trigger function**

```cs
[FunctionName("Repro_HttpStart")]
public async Task<IActionResult> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "repro/{uid}")]
    HttpRequest req, string uid,
    [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient entityClient,
    ILogger log)
{
    var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(ReproEntity), uid);
    var entityState = await entityClient.ReadEntityStateAsync<ReproEntity>(entityId);
    if (!(entityState.EntityExists && entityState.EntityState.Activated))
    {
        await entityClient.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, nameof(IReproEntity.InitializeMonitoringAsync));

        return new NotFoundObjectResult(new {error = $"The actor {uid} does not exist"});
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(new
    {
        entityState.EntityState.LoopCount, entityState.EntityState.Activated
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, for anyone else experiencing this issue, this issue was fixed in version 2.2.2 in the package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1282